# Mule ESB Startup Script Parameters

Tags: mule, esb

Mule is running as a Windows Service, and when the server is restarted we need the flows to start back up in a very specific manner. 
I have edited the bat file located in $HOME\bin\mule.bat
with these parameters:

```
./mule -app app1:app2:app3 start
```

However this does not appears to make a difference in the startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from Mule. 
On Windows

Run as Windows Service:

Follow the next steps to control the order with a system variable.

- Stop the windows service.
- Create a system variable MULE_STARTUP_ORDER containing the desired order (apps separated by ":") i.e.:APP1:APP2:APP3
- Add the next lines to the $MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf file:

  wrapper.app.parameter.10=-app
  wrapper.app.parameter.11=%MULE_STARTUP_ORDER%
- Start the windows service.
- The order should be the expected.

Note: With this method you need to manually add/delete applications to the MULE_STARTUP_ORDER variable for them to start

Answer (score 0):

It maybe of help to others running Mule 3.8 Standalone as a Window service, but this worked for me.
Remove the existing Mule service (if it exists) by running the following from the command line

> ${MULE_HOME}\bin>mule remove

Where ${MULE_HOME} is the directory where Mule is installed

Edit the following file
\Mule\bin\mule.bat

> set MULE_OPTS=set.MULE_APP=%MULE_APP%
>   set.MULE_APP_LONG=%MULE_APP_LONG% set.MULE_HOME="%MULE_HOME%"
>   set.MULE_BASE="%MULE_BASE%" set.MULE_LIB=%MULE_LIB%
>   wrapper.working.dir=%_REALPATH% **wrapper.app.parameter.1=-app**
>   **wrapper.app.parameter.2="appName1:appName2"**  wrapper.app.parameter.3=%3 
>   wrapper.app.parameter.4=%4  wrapper.app.parameter.5=%5 
>   wrapper.app.parameter.6=%6  wrapper.app.parameter.7=%7 
>   wrapper.app.parameter.8=%8 wrapper.app.parameter.9=%9

Where appName1 and appName2 are the names of my Mule applications in \Mule\apps

Install Mule as a service again

> ${MULE_HOME}\bin>mule install

Start your Mule service and check the logs to confirm the Mule apps are starting in the order expected.

Finally, if you wished to do the same from the command line, then try

> ${MULE_HOME}\bin>mule -app=appName1:appName2

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Where did you found out that would even work?
Have a look over here in the docs about starting/stopping Mule.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/starting-and-stopping-mule-esb

As far as i know that isn't possible.
You can change the initial state of your flows in Anypoint Studio to stopped.
That will help you out for the flows that you don't want to start after restart.
However you should start them afterwards manually via MMC or via the API.

Comment: from the Mule Docs page: (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/application-deployment#starting-mule) Start mule by running <MULE_HOME>/bin/mule or starting Mule as a service. By default, applications in the <MULE_HOME>/apps directory will be deployed. You can also designate specific applications to start (separated by the colon - :) and Mule 3.0 will respect the order when starting the applications. In this scenario, only the applications specified will be started.

Start Mule by specifying an app to run:

mule -app foo

Comment: But what do you expect or trying to achieve? Maybe they start fast after eachother so you don't notice it. Do you need an interval for a specfied amount of time?